# Running webapp developed with Glassfish4 on Tomcat7

Tags: java, glassfish, tomcat7

Can the web application developed with Glassfish4 be normally deployed and run on Tomcat7 as a .war file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally no. Glassfish 4 (even the web profile), is a java ee 7 container with support for ejb, jpa, cdi etc..

Tomcat is a lightweight servlet-container, tomcat 7 supports servlet 3.0 and EL 2.2 for example. Which is just a small subset of what glassfish (and java-ee has to offer)

**[Snapshot](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) from Tomcat page**

```
Apache Tomcat   7.0.x   8.0.x
Actual release  7.0.47  8.0.0-RC5
Servlet Spec    3.0     3.1
JSP Spec        2.2     2.3
EL Spec         2.2     3.0
WebSocket Spec  1.0     1.0
```

**The [java ee 7 web profile](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-eval-spec/WebProfile.pdf) specification** states that the following components are required:

```
• Servlet 3.1
• JavaServer Pages (JSP) 2.3
• Expression Language (EL) 3.0
• Debugging Support for Other Languages (JSR-45) 1.0
• Standard Tag Library for JavaServer Pages (JSTL) 1.2
• JavaServer Faces (JSF) 2.2
• Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) 2.0
• Java API for WebSocket (WebSocket) 1.0
• Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P) 1.0
• Common Annotations for the Java Platform (JSR-250) 1.2
• Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) 3.2 Lite
• Java Transaction API (JTA) 1.2
• Java Persistence API (JPA) 2.1
• Bean Validation 1.1
• Managed Beans 1.0
• Interceptors 1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends: glassfish is a **application server**, tomcat is a **servlet container**

if you used JPA, EJB, or any other JEE component, forget about tomcat (unless you add libs for your own).

otherwise, if you used only web profile, you can deploy it on tomcat.